# PyV8 in threads - how to make it work?

Tags: python, multithreading, v8

Using [PyV8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) in the main program is ok.
But even if I run it in 1 thread (not main program itself, but 1 additional thread in it)

```
class TaskThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, task):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.task = task

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.task.run()
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

a single line `self.task.run()` which has this code:

```
context = PyV8.JSContext(self.window)     # <- this stops everything
```

freezes the whole program.

I already understood that PyV8 "doesn't like" threads, but still how can I use it for threaded tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a solution while looking in http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/source/browse/trunk/PyV8.py

If you start thread like:

```
t = YourThreadClass()
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

just start it in this way:

```
with PyV8.JSLocker():
    t.start()
```

when you need to run javascript:

```
with PyV8.JSLocker():
    self.context.enter()
    print self.context.eval('1+1')
    self.context.leave()
```

Looks like it solves the problem.

Comment: i didnt seem to need to lock the locker when starting the thread, only when creating the context in the new thread